# jQuery Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a realtime notification script where every time a certain text is found in my file, it'll play a sound. This is what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTextfile() {
        $.get('myfile.txt', { cache:false }, function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf("Hello World") > -1) {
                document.write("Hello World is found");
                var audio = new Audio('wb.wav');
                audio.play();
            } else {
                document.write("It's NOT found");
                var audio = new Audio('wn.wav');
                audio.play();
            } 
            setTimeout(getTextfile, 1000);
        },'text');
    } 
    getTextfile();
</script>
```

And `myfile.txt` looks like this:

```
Line one
line two
Hello World
line four
```

But on my chrome browser I get this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

`myfile.txt` changes dynamically so it should play a different sound every time it finds the text I'm looking for or doesn't find it without me having to refresh the browser. How can I solve this ?

Comment: have you tried increasing the timeout delay?

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem, but note that you're sending `cache: false` as a parameter to the request, you're not stopping jQuery caching the response. If you want to stop caching use `$.ajax` and set `cache: false`, or call `$.ajaxSetup([ cache: false })` before your `$.get` request.

Comment: What is the size of the wm.wav and wb.wav files? Have you tryed without the lines loading those files?

Comment: Could you set up an example of this issue in a http://jsfiddle.net as I can't see a reason for the error you're getting in this code. Are you sure it's this code block causing the problem?

Comment: Nothing in that snippet stands out to me as being obviously "wrong". Can you narrow down what specifically is breaking?

Comment: try moving `var audio = new Audio('wb.wav');` and `var audio = new Audio('wn.wav');` outside `gettextfile`'s scope, and compare the results.

Comment: Did you try to replace your `getTextfile();` by `setTimeout(getTextfile, 1000);` and remove `setTimeout(getTextfile, 1000);` which is inside `getTextfile();`? That should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi everyone, I found what's causing the problem, it's `document.write()` that's causing it. After I got rid of `document.write()` everything works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found what's causing the problem, it's `document.write()` that's causing it. After I got rid of `document.write()` everything works perfectly. Thank you